# Binding ActionStream into mat-checkbox Checked and Indeterminate Not Working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, reactive-programming

I have this action stream that is bound to a material-checkbox.

```
  private isAllItemsCheckedSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<AllItemsCheckedState>(new AllItemsCheckedState(false,false));
  isAllItemsCheckedAction$  = this.isAllItemsCheckedSubject$.asObservable();
```

This is the definition of AllItemsCheckedState -

```
export class AllItemsCheckedState{
  constructor(isChecked, isIndeterminate){
    this.Checked = isChecked;
    this.Indeterminate = isIndeterminate;
  }
  Checked = false;
  Indeterminate = false;
}
```

Then I am trying to bind this action stream using async pipe into the checked and indeterminate props of this mat-checkbox

```
   <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                        (change)="someChangeEvent($event)"
                        [checked]="(isAllItemsCheckedAction$ | async)?.Checked"
                        [indeterminate]="(isAllItemsCheckedAction$ | async)?.Indeterminate">
```

ALL Teams

It is not working, although I am sure that I am calling the isAllItemsCheckedSubject$.next(new AllItemsCheckedState(true, true) on some streams. The checkbox does not reflect the checked and indeterminate values emitted by the action stream .
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is not working? are you getting some error?

Comment: @VimalPatel it does not reflect the new state values for the indeterminate and checked props of the mat checkbox. I called the isAllItemsCheckedSubject$.next(new AllItemsCheckedState(false, true) inside another stream, but it does not nake the checkbox look indeterminate

Comment: Can you try creating a sample using stackblitz or codesandbox as far as I can say this should work?

Comment: Yes, what @VimalPatel said. Creating a stackblitz that demonstrates your issue (not your entire application) will help us help you. We can better see the exact issue and try out solutions.